# How to specify configuration file for common_test running tests with rebar

Tags: erlang, rebar, common-test

I have a common test suite and I need to perform it with **rebar**. Usually it is done with command

```
rebar ct suites=mysuite
```

But there is an obstacle. My suite is required configuration file and I need to specify it when I am performing tests. **ct_run** allows to do it with

```
ct_run -config <configfile>
```

Does anybody know how can I specify config file with **rebar**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm looking at the [source code](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_ct.erl), and it doesn't look like you can specify one by name.

It's hard coded to look in your `test` directory for the following files:

- `test.config` for the `-ct_config` option
- `app.config` for the `-config` option

If that doesn't work for you, you could probably patch it to take a `rebar.config` parameter instead.

Comment: It works for me. Unfortunatly it is true that ct config file test.config is harcoded in rebar source code. Perhaps I'll create a patch to have possibility to set a config in command line.

Answer (score 3):

Update: use `rebar3` instead of `rebar`

Add following to `rebar.config`:

```
{ct_opts, [
  {config, "./config/test.config"}
]}.
```

More details [here](http://www.rebar3.org/docs/configuration#common-test).